# Converting single result of an MDX set query to a calculated measure

Tags: set, mdx

I have a SET calculated member that returns me the first invoice date of a specific client ID. This set uses the CurrentSalesPeriod which is also a single result generated from a set.

The problem is that I want to find a workaround so that I'm not forced to use this set on my rows. I would like to make this a measure so I can use it in my columns and for other purposes.

Could anyone help me with that? Is it possible at all in MDX? The query below is working but I would like to use this in another query where I am not allowed to put it on the rows.

```
SET [First Invoice Date] AS
    Iif(
        COUNT(
            NonEmpty(
                [Date invoice].[Invoice date].[Invoice date],
                [CurrentSalesPeriod]
                * Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date).Parent.Lag(1).LastChild)
                * [Point of sale].[Client id].&[46]
                * {[Measures].[YTD Sales]}
            )
        ) = 0,
        {[Date invoice].[Bonus Calendar - Week].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER.UNKNOWNMEMBER},
        Head(
            NonEmpty(
                [Date invoice].[Invoice date].[Invoice date],
                [CurrentSalesPeriod]
                * Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date).Parent.Lag(1).LastChild)
                * [Point of sale].[Client id].&[46]
                * {[Measures].[YTD Sales]}
            ), 1
        )
)

 SET [CurrentSalesPeriod] AS
    Tail( 
        NonEmpty(
            [Point of sale].[Management period].[Management period],
            {[Measures].[Sales amount]}
            * Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date))
            * [Point of sale].[Client id].&[46]
        ), 1
    )
```

Comment: `Aggregate` is the usual way to convert a set to a member - I'm unsure what the extra complexity of your request is that means this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pick a dimension that is not going to be used, and tag on an aggregated member that is the aggregation of your custom set - I don't know your cube but try replacing `[AnotherDimension].[AnotherHierarchy].` in the following with a little used Dim.Hier in your cube:

```
SET [First Invoice Date] AS
    Iif(
        COUNT(
            NonEmpty(
                [Date invoice].[Invoice date].[Invoice date],
                [CurrentSalesPeriod]
                * Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date).Parent.Lag(1).LastChild)
                * [Point of sale].[Client id].&[46]
                * {[Measures].[YTD Sales]}
            )
        ) = 0,
        {[Date invoice].[Bonus Calendar - Week].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER.UNKNOWNMEMBER},
        Head(
            NonEmpty(
                [Date invoice].[Invoice date].[Invoice date],
                [CurrentSalesPeriod]
                * Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date).Parent.Lag(1).LastChild)
                * [Point of sale].[Client id].&[46]
                * {[Measures].[YTD Sales]}
            ), 1
        )
)

 SET [CurrentSalesPeriod] AS
    Tail( 
        NonEmpty(
            [Point of sale].[Management period].[Management period],
            {[Measures].[Sales amount]}
            * Ytd(StrToMember(@PAR_Date))
            * [Point of sale].[Client id].&[46]
        ), 1
    )
MEMBER [AnotherDimension].[AnotherHierarchy].[Agg_FirstInvoiceDate] AS
    Aggregate(
      [First Invoice Date]
    )
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want this set as a measure and what it's implication might be, but if you want the date as a measure, then you can simply add one more calculated measure and use the `membervalue` property to store the value of this date. Adding the definition of the calculated measure only..

```
MEMBER Measures.FirstInvoiceDate AS
[First Invoice Date].Item(0).MEMBERVALUE
```

In the final select, just use this new measure. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Hi Sourav, Srry for the late notice. I actually tried your suggestion and it worked yesterday! I did not manage to do it direct from the set as u suggested, but I could when I added item(0).membervalue in the query of the set. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark this as an answer/upvote in that case.